# Faster alternative to numpy for manual element-wise operations on large arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, optimization

I have some code that was originally written in C (by someone else) using C-style malloc arrays. I later converted a lot of it to C++ style, using `vector<vector<vector<complex>>>` arrays for consistency with the rest of my project. I never timed it, but both methods seemed to be of similar speed.

I recently started a new project in python, and I wanted to use some of this old code. Not wanting to move data back and for between projects, I decided to port this old code into python so that it's all in one project. I naively typed up all of the code in python syntax, replacing any arrays in the old code with numpy arrays (initialising them like this `array = np.zeros(list((1024, 1024)), dtype=complex)`). The code works fine, but it is excruciatingly slow. If I had to guess, I would say it's on the order of 1000 times slower.

Now having looked into it, I see that a lot of people say numpy is very slow for element-wise operations. While I have used some of the numpy functions for common mathematical operations, such as FFTs and matrix multiplication, most of my code involves nested for loops. A lot of it is pretty complicated and doesn't seem to me to be amenable to reducing to simple array operations that are faster in numpy.

So, I'm wondering if there is an alternative to numpy that is faster for these kind of calculations. The ideal scenario would be that there is a module that I can import that has a lot of the same functionality, so I don't have to rewrite much of my code (i.e., something that can do FFTs and initialises arrays in the same way, etc.), but failing that, I would be happy with something that I could at least use for the more computationally demanding parts of the code and cast back and forth between the numpy arrays as needed.

cpython arrays sounded promising, but a lot of benchmarks I've seen don't show enough of a difference in speed for my purposes. To give an idea of the kind of thing I'm talking about, this is one of the methods that is slowing down my code. This is called millions of times, and the `vz_at()` method contains a lookup table and does some interpolation to give the final return value:

```
    def tra(self, tr, x, y, z_number, i, scalex, idx, rmax2, rminsq):
        M = 1024
        ixo = int(x[i] / scalex)
        iyo = int(y[i] / scalex)
        nx1 = ixo - idx
        nx2 = ixo + idx
        ny1 = iyo - idx
        ny2 = iyo + idx

        for ix in range(nx1, nx2 + 1):
            rx2 = x[i] - float(ix) * scalex
            rx2 = rx2 * rx2
            ixw = ix
            while ixw < 0:
                ixw = ixw + M
            ixw = ixw % M
            for iy in range(ny1, ny2 + 1):
                rsq = y[i] - float(iy) * scalex
                rsq = rx2 + rsq * rsq
                if rsq <= rmax2:
                    iyw = iy
                    while iyw < 0:
                        iyw = iyw + M
                    iyw = iyw % M
                    if rsq < rminsq:
                        rsq = rminsq
                    vz = P.vz_at(z_number[i], rsq)
                    tr[ixw, iyw] += vz
```

All up, there are a couple of thousands of lines of code; this is just a small snippet to give an example. To be clear, a lot of my arrays are 1024x1024x1024 or 1024x1024 and are complex-valued. Others are one-dimensional arrays on the order of a million elements. What's the best way I can speed these element-wise operations up?

Comment: Yeah, the alternative is C or C++. If your `numpy` code is characterizable as "most of my code involves nested for loops." and you don't think you can use vectorized numpy operations to re-implement it, then `numpy` and probably `python` are not the right tools. However, I think you will find that your code might very well be vectorizeable.

Comment: Your other options is Cython (which is what I think you meant by cpython, which is not Cython, it is the canonical C implementation of Python).

Comment: There seem to be 2 main productive `cython` uses.  One is to use `cython` code to interface existing `c` or `c++` with Python.  The other is to rewrite just the slow pieces (iterative stuff that can't be cast into good numpy) in `cython`.  `cython` gives the best speed when it can generate pure `c` code, without calls to create or use Python/numpy objects.

Comment: As I already have the complete code in C, it's probably simplest to just transfer data between the two projects. I wouldn't have bothered porting the code if I realised it would cause headaches; it just never occurred to me that it would be significantly slower. Regarding cython/cpython, I saw a lot of comments suggesting cython when I was looking for a solution, but then I saw comments on those comments saying that cpython was preferred. I really don't know anything about either of them.

Comment: `cpython` refers to the code that implements `Python`, or at least the main version - in other words the `c` code that runs the interpreter.

Comment: Just curious: why do you need `while ixw < 0: ixw = ixw + M` right before `ixw = ixw % M`? Are there values of `ixw` for which the while loop would make a difference?

Comment: I think you're right that it doesn't need to be there. It does make a difference in C, and when I ported the code to python, it didn't occur to me that I could remove those while loops. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For information, some of your code can be made more concise and thus a bit more readable. For instance:

```
array = np.zeros(list((1024, 1024)), dtype=complex)).
```

can be written

```
array = np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype=complex)
```

As you are trying out Python, this is at least a nice benefit :-)

Now, for your problem there are several solutions in the current Python scientific landscape:

1. [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) is a just-in-time compiler for Python that is dedicated to array processing, achieving good performance when NumPy hits its limits.

   Pros: Little to no modification of your code as you just write plain Python, shows good performance in many situations.  Numba should recognize some NumPy operations to avoid a Numba->Python->NumPy slowdown.
   Cons: Can be tedious to install and hence to distribute Numba-based code.
2. [Cython](http://cython.org/) is a mix of Python and C to generate compiled functions. You can start from a pure Python file and accelerate the code via type annotations and the use of some "C"-isms.

   Pros: stable, widely used, relatively easy to distribute Cython-based code.
   Cons: need to rewrite the performance critical code, even if only in part.

As an additional hint, Nicolas Rougier (a French scientist) wrote an online book on many situations where you can make use of NumPy to speed up Python code: http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm having a look at Numba now. However, as I said in another comment, because I already have the code in C, it may end up just being easier to transfer data between the projects as needed.

Comment: So, I see a definite and significant improvement for many methods with Numba, but it spits out a whole heap of errors for some of the problem methods. It think if I can get them to work, it will be a very serviceable solution. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.